# Are Master's becoming required for USA PhD programs?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters

In the USA, many universities enroll PhD students with BSc degree. I think this is the classical scheme, which remained in the US universities. In many countries, it is almost impossible to enroll in a PhD program without MSc degree.

I am curious how is the trend for MSc programs?

At least in the USA, do more universities allow PhD enrollment with BSc degree or those allowing are shifting to MSc requirement?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the mechanics, but I always heard that the master's degree was traditionally the "booby prize" awarded to students who had failed to complete the PhD.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer: Not so, in most of the cases I know. Stopping at MS is often the additional-study-but-not-pure-research path, engineer rather than scientist. And in some fields, an MS *is* considered a Terminal Degree.

Comment: PaulProgrammer, with regards to master's degrees being "booby prizes" that's pretty rich for someone with an MBA listed on their website resume. ;-)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Maybe in the US, but it's generally impossible to get into a PhD program in Europe without having your master and doing your PhD is really only done by the small handful of people who actually want to go into research. Having a PhD won't help you much if you're looking for a job outside of research or academia.. having instead 3 years of actual work experience will be much more valuable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At least in my field (mathematics), every US PhD program I know of accepts students with a bachelor's degree.  I see no sign of this changing.

Comment: Same in computer science.

Comment: Same in physics.

Answer (score 7):

In physics, doctoral programs typically admit students with bachelor's degrees.  Some programs will award a master's degree partway through, usually upon completion of coursework and successful defense of a research proposal.  A master's degree is also a graceful way for a student who wants to leave a PhD program early to do so.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that a MSc is some kind of a door prize. I'm sure that this does happen but I don't think that it is set up that way. A certain amount of coursework is required as a part of the doctoral evaluation. A subset of which generally overlaps with the requirements for the related master's degree. Conferring the master's just recognises the work that has been done.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that an MS is a "door prize."  There are respected programs in physics that end in a master's degree, and some students leave one doctoral program with a master's because they are interested in working with a professor somewhere else.  However students who get an MS and PhD from the same department typically earn both degrees for research on the same topic.

Answer (score 4):

In the field of biology they don't require a Master's. When I interviewed with top Universities, it was pretty uncommon for the candidates to have a Master's degree. Everyone did have a Bachelor's though.