# Masters by Distance Learning accepted for PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, distance-learning, correspondence

I have done by B.Tech in Biotechnology couple of years ago. Since then I am working with a company on bioinformatics research. I also did 1 year PG Diploma in Bioinformatics from classroom program.

Most of the Indian and UK universities have this prerequisite that I need to have a masters degree for PhD. As I am currently working in a company, will correspondence or distance learning masters will be valid?

I already saw these:

[Distance learning: taken seriously?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14833/distance-learning-taken-seriously)

[Are Master's becoming required for USA PhD programs?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19559/are-masters-becoming-required-for-usa-phd-programs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skipping the *reputation* aspects discussion, programs and degrees from any *nationally accredited* higher education institutions are all valid. In US, such institutional accreditation comes in a form of an accreditation from one of several regional commissions, such as *Southern Association of Colleges and Schools Commission on Colleges (SACS-COC)*. I imagine that similar accreditation mechanisms exist in UK, India and most other countries. Keep in mind that there is a significant difference in the *educational process* and its *outcomes*, as well as, consequently, your future *career prospects*, between nationally accredited programs and degrees and the unaccredited ones. For more information, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccredited_institutions_of_higher_education) as well as articles linked in the its "See Also" section.